# How to include link in the column header of and <af:Table>

Tags: oracle-adf

I Have the table in which one of the column contains a text followed by a go-link.
I was able show the text and link. But when i click on the link, the linked page is not opening, instead the table is getting sorted.
Here is my code.
Please help me.

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.findPartsResultList.hints.eosDate.name}"
           sortable="true"
           headerText="" 
           binding="#{pageFlowScope.RequestPartMBean.colEndOfHW}"
           id="c6" 
           headerNoWrap="true" 
           noWrap="true" 
           width="180px !important" >
     <f:facet name="header">
        <af:panelGroupLayout layout="horizontal">
              <af:outputText inlineStyle="font-family:Tahoma,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-   serif;font-weight: bold;font-size:12px;color:#333333;display:block;width:108px" value="End of HW Support" noWrap="true"/>
               <af:goLink styleClass="support-css-color-blue2" text="[?]" targetFrame="_blank" destination=""/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
     </f:facet>
</af:column>
```

Comment: Does it work if you set your column sortable property to false?

Answer (score 0):

```
<af:goLink styleClass="support-css-color-blue2" text="[?]" targetFrame="_blank" destination=""/>
```

you have not mentioned any destination here `destination=""` ?

check this link for more info on go-link -

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_goLink.html

Comment: Its not about the destination, whatever the destination i give, it still not redirect to that page. it only sorts the column values.

Comment: Have you tried using a af:commandLink instead? af:goLink seems to be deprecated.